# send pdf file to a printer - print pdf

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I'm programming a web application with Visual Studio 2010 (C#). I want to send a PDF (saved in my computer) to a printer when I click a button.

To create the PDF I used iTextSharp. I tried this, but it just opens Adobe Reader:

```
               proc.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Archivos de programa\Adobe\Reader10.0\Reader\AcroRd32.exe";
               proc.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"/p /h {0}", pdfFileName);
               proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
               proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

               proc.Start();
```

Thank you in advance!!!

Answer (score 45, accepted):

this has already been asked and answered here:
[How can I send a file document to the printer and have it print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print)

The code that was used:

```
private void SendToPrinter()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = @"c:\output.pdf";
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
        if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
            p.Kill();
    }
```

it basicly opens a "hidden" pdf-reader, tells it to print, waits for it to finish then close it down

Comment: This is good solution, but what if I want to print document with manual printer setting?

Comment: WaitForInputIdle() has no effect. It seems that p is in idle-Mode after Start(). Only the sleep for 3 seconds allows Adobe to finish the spooling. This might be a problem for large documents.

Comment: It doesn't work no more on Windows 8+

Comment: Although it is printing the file without any issue, but `p.WaitForInputIdle();` doesn't return any value and the program remain stuck on this line of code