# Print to Printer in Awesomium ?

Tags: c#, printing, awesomium

How do I handle window.print() event to actual printing (Not print to PDF) in Awesomium ? I know it'll use WebView.PrintRequest Event but i don't know how to do that

http://docs.awesomium.net/1_7_0/html/E_Awesomium_Core_WebView_PrintRequest.htm

Comment: oh please, no one here knows ? even if it use psf plugin like adobe reader i would love to know how to use it..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Awesomium does not support printing to a printer device.  Instead Awesomium supports printing to a PDF file.

### The "right" way

My limited understanding of printing in Windows is that you typically needed to "paint" to the printer using a 
GDI+ drawing surface passed into your custom event handler for print events.  [The MSDN documentation for the System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument(v=vs.100).aspx) does a good job of providing an example implementation.

I imagine one could implement this lower level of printing using the Awesomium .Net SDK, however, it will likely be an uphill battle with no support
from Awesomium's developers.

### Alternatives

A decent "hack" might be to glue together Awesomium's print to PDF feature with printing a PDF file.  I can think of at least 3 ways to print a PDF file from C#:

1. Using Acrobat Reader on the end user's machine to handle printing with a .Net runtime callable wrapper (RCW) around the COM automation object for Acrobat.  See [an example of using an Acrobat RCW in VB.NET](http://www.ultimateprogrammingtutorials.info/2012/08/how-to-make-pdf-reader-in-visual-basic.html).
2. Using whatever PDF reader is on the user's machine to handle printing.  See [an example of using the .Net ProcessStartInfo with the print verb to use the default PDF application on the user's machine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17448552/1995977).
3. Using the Windows common dialogs to pick a printer, and then send the PDF to the printer for raw (direct) printing.  (This is similar to sending a PostScript [.ps] file directly to a printer).  This will only work with printers that accept PDF file directly.

### Example Implementation using #3

Below is an example of workaround option #3, using sending the Awesomium PDF file(s) directly to a printer selected by the end user.

This answer combines two existing examples: a [Microsoft KB on raw printing with .Net](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) and an [Awesomium answer for printing](http://answers.awesomium.com/questions/65/awesomiumwebviewprinttofile.html).

Running the demo loads the URL for the Microsoft KB, which includes a "Print" UI button that invokes `window.print()`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Awesomium.Core;

namespace Demo
{
    static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new PrinterDemo());
        }
    }

    public class PrinterDemo : Form
    {
        private Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl webControl;
        private PrinterSettings printerSettings;
        private string printerName;

        public PrinterDemo()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.webControl = new Awesomium.Windows.Forms.WebControl();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // webControl1
            // 
            this.webControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.webControl.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.webControl.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 562);
            this.webControl.Source = new System.Uri("http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091", System.UriKind.Absolute);
            this.webControl.TabIndex = 0;

            this.webControl.PrintRequest += WebControl_PrintRequest;
            this.webControl.PrintComplete += WebControl_PrintComplete;
            this.webControl.PrintFailed += WebControl_PrintFailed;

            // 
            // PrinterDemo
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(784, 562);
            this.Controls.Add(this.webControl);
            this.Name = "PrinterDemo";
            this.Text = "PrinterDemo";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);
        }

        /// <summary>Handle `window.print()` events</summary>
        private void WebControl_PrintRequest(object sender, PrintRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Print();
            e.Handled = true;
        }


        /// <summary>Event handler for successful printing</summary>
        private void WebControl_PrintComplete(object sender, PrintCompleteEventArgs e)
        {
            // Print the file to the printer.
            if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(printerName))
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (string file in e.Files)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Printing file {0}", file);
                RawPrinterHelper.SendFileToPrinter(printerName, file);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Event handler for unsuccessful printing</summary>
        private void WebControl_PrintFailed(object sender, PrintOperationEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("MyApp", "Printing failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        }

        /// <summary>Sends a PDF file to the printer</summary>
        private void Print()
        {
            PrintDialog printerDialog;
            int requestId;
            string path = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

            if (!webControl.IsLive)
                return;

            printerDialog = new PrintDialog();
            printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            printerDialog.PrinterSettings = printerSettings;

            if (DialogResult.OK == printerDialog.ShowDialog(this))
            {
                printerName = printerDialog.PrinterSettings.PrinterName;
                requestId = webControl.PrintToFile(path, PrintConfig.Default);
            }
        }
    }

    public class RawPrinterHelper
    {
        // Structure and API declarions:
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
        public class DOCINFOA
        {
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDocName;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pOutputFile;
            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
            public string pDataType;
        }
        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

        [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

        // SendBytesToPrinter()
        // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
        // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
        // Returns true on success, false on failure.
        public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
        {
            Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
            IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
            DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
            bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

            di.pDocName = "My C#.NET RAW Document";
            di.pDataType = "RAW";

            // Open the printer.
            if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
            {
                // Start a document.
                if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
                {
                    // Start a page.
                    if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
                    {
                        // Write your bytes.
                        bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
                        EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
                    }
                    EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
                }
                ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
            }
            // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
            // about why not.
            if (bSuccess == false)
            {
                dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            }
            return bSuccess;
        }

        public static bool SendFileToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szFileName)
        {
            // Open the file.
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(szFileName, FileMode.Open);
            // Create a BinaryReader on the file.
            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            // Dim an array of bytes big enough to hold the file's contents.
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[fs.Length];
            bool bSuccess = false;
            // Your unmanaged pointer.
            IntPtr pUnmanagedBytes = new IntPtr(0);
            int nLength;

            nLength = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length);
            // Read the contents of the file into the array.
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(nLength);
            // Allocate some unmanaged memory for those bytes.
            pUnmanagedBytes = Marshal.AllocCoTaskMem(nLength);
            // Copy the managed byte array into the unmanaged array.
            Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Send the unmanaged bytes to the printer.
            bSuccess = SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pUnmanagedBytes, nLength);
            // Free the unmanaged memory that you allocated earlier.
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pUnmanagedBytes);
            return bSuccess;
        }
        public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string szPrinterName, string szString)
        {
            IntPtr pBytes;
            Int32 dwCount;
            // How many characters are in the string?
            dwCount = szString.Length;
            // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
            // the string to ANSI text.
            pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
            // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
            SendBytesToPrinter(szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
            Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I was able to compile and run this example as a single file named `demo.cs` with the following command line:

```
SETLOCAL
PATH C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\;%PATH%
IF EXIST demo.exe DEL demo.exe
csc.exe /target:winexe /lib:"%ProgramFiles%\Awesomium Technologies LLC\Awesomium SDK\1.7.3.0\wrappers\Awesomium.NET\Assemblies" /reference:Awesomium.Core.dll,Awesomium.Windows.Forms.dll demo.cs 
demo.exe
ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: thx, really appreciated! do you have that source code (the solution files and others) ? i want to follow your implementation of this.

Comment: @denny, this is a working example in a single file; you don't need Visual Studio for this, you could just compile on the command line with csc.exe.  I updated the post to show an example

Comment: @steveJensen: thx for reply. i have some difficulties when tried to compile that code.  app.exe just throw System.IO.FileNotFoundException. Nevertheless i managed to run your code in Visual Studio, launch Awesomium, and print the page i want. But it just print a lot of strange code. is it RAW data do you mean?

Comment: just like this: [link to image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_KPBXT3q6YcOFNNWEF5T203aDQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @denny, your printout contains the actual PDF contents. It looks like you are using a thermal point-of-sale printer, which likely isn't sophisticated enough for printing PDF from a RAW stream.  You are likely going to need to send the PDF file to a PDF viewer, which were options #1 and #2 in my answer.  Do you want to print receipts?  What if you send structured data from Javascript to C#, and have C# properly print the text?

Comment: yes, i used awesomium to print receipt using thermal miniPOS printer. I want to use your option #1, but it'll invoke print dialog to user. I don't want the user to cancel invoice printing. So, how exactly does i send structured data to C# ? build server to listen to incoming print request maybe ?