# Simultaneous printing from two printers in C#

Tags: c#, printers

I do not know how to do it. There are two printers. They need to print documents at the same time. Actually the algorithm can be; If you are printing something on the system, the two printers reprint this document.

```
foreach (string printer in System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters)
{
    if (printer == "ZJ-58")
    {

    }

    if (printer == "ZJ-58-2")
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: I would first start with printing using C#, then try to print to multiple printers. This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20692697/how-to-print-a-document-using-c-sharp-code

Comment: To start with, define "same time". Also, in your code, use `||` and have just one `if` so you don't repeat the printing code.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to trigger the printing at the same time you could fire tasks in parallel (here I'm assuming you have a print function which returns a task). Eg:

```
var printers = new List<object>();
var printerTasks = printers.Select(printer =>
{
     if (printer == "ZJ-58")
     {
          return printer.print();
     }

     if (printer == "ZJ-58-2")
     {
          return printer.print();
     }
 });
 Task.WaitAll(printerTasks);
```

Comment: I downvoted this because the statement *here I'm assuming you have a print function which returns a task* is a bad assumption. There's no indication in the question that this is the case, and if it's *not* the case, your answer is wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what I'm looking for is triggering printers when any printing is done on the computer.

Comment: Yeah, I should have asked for clarifications instead of blindly throwing help.