# How to send and emulate thermal printer in .net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, printing, thermal-printer

I have this printer
http://tecelectronica.com.mx/pos/tm-188.html

But I dont have access to the printer physically, I need to know how to print via .net and also if there an utility to emulate this printer to run some tests.
Thank in advance.

Comment: please have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print