# Printing PDF automatically from c# code

Tags: c#, pdf, printing

I am trying to print using the below c# and iTextSharp code, can some one help me. It does not get printed.

```
var document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();             
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memStream);
document.Open();
var reader = new PdfReader("C:\\test1.pdf");
PdfContentByte content = writer.DirectContent;

Int32 i;
int pageCount = 1;
for (i = 0; i <= pageCount - 1; i++)
{
    document.NewPage();
    PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i + 1);
    content.AddTemplate(page, 0, 0);
}
writer.SetOpenAction(new PdfAction(PdfAction.PRINTDIALOG));
document.Close();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send a file document to the printer and have it print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print)

Comment: @Tsukasa, thanks for your flag. However it would be good to still note what you said in your answer: "iTextSharp can't print".

Comment: The posted code asks a conforming PDF renderer to automatically prompt the user to print the PDF when opened. It will not automatically print. As noted above, iTextSharp cannot print because iTextSharp is not a renderer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **[Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/)** library to print the pdf file.

If yo need a Ghostscript wrapper for .NET you can take a look at **[Ghostscript.NET](http://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET)** library.

Printing sample via Ghostscript.NET can be found here: **https://ghostscriptnet.codeplex.com/discussions/470946**