# How to print PDF directly to printer with C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing

How can I print PDF directly to a printer with (asp.net) C#?

I actually want to print the PDF directly without showing a dialog on the server side in asp.net c#

Comment: do you ever try rdlc report?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I send a file document to the printer and have it print?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that thread concerns local Printing from a WinForms application, this one concerns Printing via ASP.NET.

Comment: Forget it, there's no way you can bypass the browser print dialog. And for good reason too. I wouldn't want my printer to start spitting out random spam messages when I visit a web site.

Answer (score 1):

You'll be hard pressed to make this from asp.net if the server isn't residing in the same LAN as the client and can have the same printers installed, this due to security functions inside the web browsers not allowing websites to print to a local machine. You might get a solution for this if you implement some ActiveX Component or Java applet to run this (even seen it in Silverlight, but that's going away).

Something like http://www.vbgold.com/index.shtml#AdvancedPDFPrinter might help you achieve what you're looking for.