# C#, already able to print using hidden process, how to print to specific printer

Tags: c#, windows, printing, process

I have the following C# code that successfully prints a file that it is provided. This is in Windows 7.

```
    // Uses the Default settings of the Windows Environment to open the file and send to printer
    // Seen: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6106155
    public void printPdfHiddenProcess(string filename)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        Process p;

        // Set process setting to be hidden
        info.Verb = "print";
        info.FileName = filename;
        info.CreateNoWindow = true;
        info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

        // Start hidden process
        p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();

        // Give the process some time
        p.WaitForInputIdle();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // Close it
        if (p.CloseMainWindow() == false)
        {
            p.Close();
        }
    }
```

However, this causes it to print to the default printer. ProcessStartInfo doesn't appear to provide specific methods I can use to pass the printer name, but I might be missing something.

How can I print to a specific printer using a hidden process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Print`goes to the default, to use another you would use `PrintTo` and name it. Similar to *Save* vs *Save As*

```
info.Verb = "PrintTo";               // was "Print"
string PrinterName = "Some Printer"; // add printer specific name here...
info.Arguments = PrinterName;
```

More info: [Print documents... using the printto verb](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/987b3ff2-879b-4b44-bd38-17598de5f549/print-documents-rtf-pdf-etc-using-the-printto-verb-from-inside-a-windows-service?forum=csharpgeneral)

Comment: Looks promising but it isn't working for me yet. Will read that link and see if I can figure it out.

Comment: I got it working! I had to change info.Arguments, I passed the printer name directly as in `info.Arguments = printerName;` and it worked. If you can update your answer to at least note this I'll gladly accept.

Comment: Updated answer with your comments