# How to print PDF documents or other printable files in UWP?

Tags: c#, pdf, uwp, windows-10

The example that Microsoft provides [(Github)](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Printing) doesn't make much sense since it's printing a XAML page and not a real PDF document.

In iOS I can simple send a printable file (image, pdf, etc) to the printer and call it a day.

Why does printing a simply PDF document so complicated in UWP? No wonder no one supports this excuse of a frame work.

Don't link me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print) since it doesn't work in UWP.

Comment: Is this a real question or just a rant?

Comment: a real question. the last part is a rant tho

Comment: @RyanWilson that doesn't work in UWP, sir. but thanks

Comment: @UweKeim Down voting this question won't help solving the problem

Comment: @max.mustermann, I think you could create win32 app to process print and then convert it to uwp app with desktop-bridge.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT  i dont think that's a great solution to convert my uwp app to a desktop-bridge app just to get the print function working, since i already have a wonderfully working app that can read pdf, connects to online database etc. Now please remove the duplicate flag since it is not a duplicate!

Comment: Ok, I have done.