# How to bypass print dialog option programatically in win-forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to save a html content in pdf from a webbrowser control in win-form

```
this.webBrowser1.DocumentText = htmltext;
```

i have used this to render html text in webbrowser
now using below to print that html content into pdf

```
webBrowser1.Print();
```

but when i use this it will open a print dialog box, but i don't want to show it and wants to do give printer and file name from code side

Comment: Why do you want to _print_ this in a PDF ? Why not use a third party library like iText7 to create a PDF and write your text to that PDF ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I send a file document to the printer and have it print?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print)

Comment: I have tried this stuff but not getting appropriate results that i  want

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with @MarleneHE that you should be using a library to convert HTML to PDF for this, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/564650/convert-html-to-pdf-in-net) for discussion on this.

If you are insistent on using the PDF printer, have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6103705/how-can-i-send-a-file-document-to-the-printer-and-have-it-print) which uses ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden to get around the printer dialog:

```c#
private void SendToPrinter()
{
   ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
   info.Verb = "print";
   info.FileName = @"c:\output.pdf";
   info.CreateNoWindow = true;
   info.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

   Process p = new Process();
   p.StartInfo = info;
   p.Start();

   p.WaitForInputIdle();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
   if (false == p.CloseMainWindow())
      p.Kill();
}
```