Using System.Drawing.Printing in C# throws an error
The problem is that when I use the 'System.Drawing.Printing' I get an error when initializing the 'PrinterSettings' that is supposed to be inside the 'System.Drawing.Printing'. It's a project with .NET Framework 4.7.2.
Error Images: 

Using's:
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System.Timers;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.Linq;

Code:
string printerName = "PrinterName";
int l_Pages = 0; 

var printerSettings = new PrinterSettings(); //* Error
var installedPrinters = PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters.Cast<string>().ToList(); //* Error
int z = installedPrinters.FindIndex(p => p.Equals(printerName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

if (l_Pages == 0)
{
    if (z > installedPrinters.Count - 1) //* Error
    {
        printerSettings.PrinterName = installedPrinters[0];
    }
    else
    {
        printerSettings.PrinterName = installedPrinters[i];
    }
}

NuGet Packages

Oracle.ManagedDataAcess v19.18.0
System.Drawing.Common v8.0.4


I am trying to get the printers installed and set the default printer as well as set the printer orientation and scale using Printing package or another option compatible with .NET Framework 4.7.2

Are you sure this is a .NET 4.x project and not a .NET 5+ project?

I think so, I looked at the configuration and I have as target platform NET Framework 4.7.2 I guess that's what you mean.

System.Drawing.Printing is for desktop Windows Forms applications. Do you have a desktop Windows Forms app, or a web ASP.NET application, as your tag implies?

Im creating a 'Console App (.NET Framework)'

@PsychoMx - There seems to be no easy solution for Console Apps, maybe third party libraries. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57909756/how-do-i-print-in-net-based-non-gui-applications
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67838804/net-c-sharp-sending-a-file-to-the-printer-from-a-console-application

Check the documentation, you don't access PrinterSettings directly:

Typically, you access a PrinterSettings through
PrintDocument.PrinterSettings or PageSettings.PrinterSettings
properties to modify printer settings.

They also have a code sample there: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing.printersettings?view=netframework-4.7.2

Other pages implicitly indicate the entire System.Drawing.Printing namespace is for Windows Forms apps, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.printing?view=netframework-4.7.2#remarks and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/windows-forms-print-support?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8
