Print a PDF using a .NET Console Application
I’m working on creating a C# tool that sends a PDF file to a specific printer. This tool will run once a day via the task scheduler on a server. I've found several ways to achieve this, but most require using the System.Drawing and System.Drawing.Printing libraries.
The challenge with these libraries is that they depend on either a Windows Forms Application or the System.Drawing.Common library, which causes me a problem in a task scheduler environment. This is due to the lack of a graphical interface, and the risk that the application may enter a waiting state or an infinite loop if it cannot find the necessary graphical environment.
Specifically, the problem occurs only when I run the application from the task scheduler on the server; it works correctly when executed locally.
When the application is in a "running" state, it seems to enter an infinite loop where it does nothing, and the printing does not work. I don’t see any logs on Sentry, which leads to resource locking and requires manual intervention to stop the task.
I’ve also considered sending the print command to a third-party application (e.g., Adobe) to handle the printing, but this approach is not ideal for a task scheduler on a server.
I reviewed this question, but it doesn't specifically address the functionality of running in a task scheduler environment, and the provided answers do not offer solutions tailored to my specific problem.
Does anyone have suggestions on how to print a PDF file to a specific printer in a C# console application that runs under the task scheduler, using open-source solutions?
Is there a more 'low-level' way to execute the PDF printing? For example, by sending the file directly to the print driver?
using System.Drawing.Printing;
using System.IO;
using PdfiumViewer;

public bool QueueDocument(string printerPath, string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = printerPath;

        using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Load(filePath))
        using (PrintDocument printDocumentPdf = document.CreatePrintDocument())
        {
            printDocumentPdf.PrinterSettings = printDocument.PrinterSettings;
            printDocumentPdf.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();
            printDocumentPdf.Print();
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
        return false;
    }
}


what about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41751184

I managed to resolve the issue by changing my approach entirely. Initially, I was using System.Drawing.Printing, but this caused problems when running the application through Task Scheduler on a server without a graphical environment. Instead, I switched to using native Windows API functions to send the file directly to the printer in RAW mode, bypassing the need for a graphical interface:
[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool OpenPrinter(string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter")]
public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, int level, ref DOCINFOA pDocInfo);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter")]
public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter")]
public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter")]
public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

[DllImport("winspool.drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, int dwCount, out int dwWritten);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct DOCINFOA
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string pDocName;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string pOutputFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string pDataType;
}

public static bool QueueDocument(string printerName, string filePath)
{
    bool result = false;
    IntPtr pBytes = IntPtr.Zero; // Pointer to the data to send to the printer
    byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

    if (OpenPrinter(printerName, out var hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
    {
        var docInfo = new DOCINFOA
        {
            pDocName = Path.GetFileName(filePath),
            pOutputFile = null,
            pDataType = "RAW"
        };
        try
        {
            if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, ref docInfo) && StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
            {
                pBytes = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(fileBytes.Length);
                Marshal.Copy(fileBytes, 0, pBytes, fileBytes.Length);
                result = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, fileBytes.Length, out _);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            if (pBytes != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pBytes);
            }
            EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
            EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
            ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        SentrySdk.CaptureMessage("Printer connection error", SentryLevel.Error);
    }
    return result;
}

This approach bypasses the issues I faced with System.Drawing.Printing and works smoothly with Task Scheduler, as it doesn’t rely on a graphical interface.
Note: While this solution works well for the current case, there may still be room for optimization in terms of code readability and performance. For now, it works fine, but I may revisit it later to improve its efficiency and clarity.
Hope this helps anyone else facing similar issues!
