# Threads for WebBrowser.Print()

Tags: c#, multithreading, printing, browser

I'm trying to create GUI program that generates HTML invoices, and sends them for printing. 
I have this working. However, now I want to introduce threading.

I have a form with a `BackgroundWorker`. The Background worker runs this code:

```
#region BackGroundWorker   
private void bg_htmlGeneration_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
   //SOME MORE CODE..

   foreach (XElement ele in Lib.GetInvoiceElement(inv, ico.Supplier))
   {
      PrintDocument(Lib.CreateHTMLFile());
   }
}
#endregion  


public void PrintDocument(string fileName)
{
    var th = new Thread(() =>
    {
        WebBrowser webBrowserForPrinting = new WebBrowser();
        webBrowserForPrinting.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(PrintDocumentHandler);
        webBrowserForPrinting.Url = new Uri(fileName);
        Application.Run();
    });
    th.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    th.Start();
}

public void PrintDocumentHandler(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Print();
    ((WebBrowser)sender).Dispose();
    Application.ExitThread();
}
```

Everything runs through fine. However, the `WebBrowser` object refuses to print. There are no errors (that are obvious), the program finishes off with nothing sent to the printer. 
When I take away the threading, the program works again.

My knowledge of threading is weak, and I'm pretty much teaching myself - so presumably I'm misunderstanding how threading priority is set.

Here's How it should work:

1. User selects Invoice(s) on Main Form, chooses to print.
2. Background thread goes away and prints them while user continues on the program.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Usually, I would access UI components (like the web browser) only from within the UI thread, not a background thread. In addition, I would not create UI elements from within a background thread.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Do you have any advice as to how I would approach this? I need to keep the Main Form available for user input (such as cancelling a print job).. so I need to only be accessing the component from the UI thread for no longer than a second.

Comment: You could try having a _hidden_ `WebBrowser` control on your form and tell this one to print (all from within the foreground thread). This _could_ work, you should give it a try first to see.

Comment: At the moment, this is what I currently have: Timer on the Form that checks for a new entry in a Singleton Queue, if entry found, print it using a new WebForm. This seems to be working, but it seems like poor practice to be doing this. There must be a library somewhere that allows HTML printing from a thread, i just need to find it.

Comment: I would doubt a lot that there are libraries out there. Rendering HTML is a _very_ complex task. Aspose.Pdf for examples allows basic HTML => PDF => Image rendering, but far from perfect.

Comment: I'll check that out as I'll need PDFs at a later date. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main problem with your code is `WebBrowser` wrong using.

[`WebBrowser`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) supposed to be used for **interactive** web-browsing, during it user do some things in the internet. But in your case you are using WebBrowser just for the **printing** after downloading the html. This is wrong by two reasons:

1. Your code creates whole Windows Forms Control and not using even half of its functionality.
2. Your code tries to use the WinForms Control in the background thread, which leads to the unexpected behaviour.

[`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class supposed to be used for

> execute a time-consuming operation (like downloads and database transactions) in the background.

Much more:

> You must be careful **not to manipulate any user-interface objects** in your `DoWork` event handler. Instead, communicate to the user interface through the `ProgressChanged` and `RunWorkerCompleted` events.

Your code will fail in the background thread, because WinForms control is a `user-interface object`.

Just for the record, [WebBrowser.Print](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.print.aspx) method invokes native windows API, so you have no chance that this will work in background. From the disassembly code:

```
this.AxIWebBrowser2.ExecWB(NativeMethods.OLECMDID.OLECMDID_PRINT, 
  NativeMethods.OLECMDEXECOPT.OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, 
  ref obj, 
  IntPtr.Zero);
```

---

So, my suggestion for your code is:

1. Remove usage of the `WebBrowser` class in the background. Use [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) instead for downloading the web content.
2. Choose other way for the printing your downloaded content. Options are:

   - [`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.aspx) implementation (example for it is [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/44330-printing-in-c#/)).
   - Use [MS Office classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.aspx) for opening and [printing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.printout.aspx) your html-files (first parameter for the Print method is a `Boolean Background`, I think this can help you). As far as I know, even in 2010 this approach works well.
   - Check other questions about printing ([here is a discussion of printing the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464261/how-to-print-files-stored-at-your-local-hard-drive-in-c), but this is the same thing, I think).

PS: in the comments you've said that you may need the `PDF` from your html. I did this by C# by two ways:

- Batching using the [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/)
- Using [Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7).
  This Add-in should be installed on the server, after that you can easily use MS Office classes for saving the output in the PDF format.

---

Some update here:

As we have an [`async/await`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh191443.aspx) and [TPL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997423.aspx) options for the time-consuming operations, I don't recommend you to use the [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) class anymore.

Comment: Following some other advice I was given, I've looked at using the IHTMLDocument2 object. This actually allows me to print from a different thread - but I'm having problems. Don't suppose you have any ideas VMAtm? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13272704/ihtmldocument2-printing-without-dialog-box