# IHTMLDocument2 Printing without Dialog Box

Tags: c#, printing, ihtmldocument2

I've been working on a project that automatically prints `HTML` invoices. It's been particularly challenging as I've needed to keep the `CSS` formatting.

Following advice, I've found myself using `IHTMLDocument2` to carry out my printing. I'm supposed to be able to:

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = new mshtml.HTMLDocument() as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
doc.write(htmlContent); //htmlContent is a string of HTML
doc.execCommand("PRINT", false, null);
```

The second argument specifies whether to produce the `Printer Options` box, but it doesn't help. I've read that using `PRINT` will always result in a dialog box - however I haven't been able to find an alternative.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

According [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#print):

> Print
>
> Opens the print dialog box so the user can print the current page.

So I think there is no way to workaround this behaviour. Try to use other classes for your application or open the print dialog box during printing.
You should note that you must provide `true` as secord parameter (`showUI [in, optional]`) in `execCommand` method.